# Facebook SDK Friend Request Redirect?

Tags: facebook, sdk, request

I have a site that allows users to request their Facebook friends to join the site. To achieve this I am using as follows in Javascript:

```
   FB.ui({ method: 'apprequests',
                message: 'Join MySite',
                //to: user_ids,
                title: 'Send your friends a MySite request'
            }
```

This works great and sends a message to all selected friends via Facebook. The problem is that the link on Facebook sends my friends to "http://apps.facebook.com/mysite/". This is my app embeded within Facebook ("Facebook App"??). What i really want is users to be sent to mysite "http://www.mysite.com" ... preferably with the FB data on the user's within the querystring.

I guess I could add my own redirect logic (assuming I could send FB data along with my url) but this feels like a hack. My guess is that I'm missing something.

If anyone has dealt with this before please let me know what I am missing here. Also I'm not attached to any particualr way that FB SDK can invite friends..anything that works is fine by me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heh, I actually just answered a similar question a moment ago (about "fanpages")... but here's the answer again in relation to websites:

From to the [Requests Dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) documentation:

> Note: Requests are **only available for Canvas apps and not websites**. Accepting a request will direct the user to the Canvas Page URL of the app that sent the Request.

So yes, if you want to use the Requests dialog for a website instead of an App, you need to set up a redirect on the App's Canvas Page, just as you suspected.

Here's an article I worked from one time to do just this (worked pretty well):

http://af-design.com/blog/2011/02/17/using-facebook-requests-to-promote-a-website/

Good luck

Comment: It's certainly easier to proceed with the manual redirect approach knowing that's currently the way it should be done. Thanks thaddeusmt